# AbsListView: ClassCastException inside onRestoreInstanceState during screen orientation change

Tags: android, android-listview, android-2.3-gingerbread

I'm using an `AbsListView` in several fragments and activities so that I can use a `ListView` in portrait mode and `GridView` in landscape.  I do all of my daily testing in ICS and JB, and this works just fine.  I started testing on GB devices (2.3.6), and I get a ClassCastException when I rotate the device with one of these screens active.  Here's the stack trace:

```
05-09 14:04:55.019: E/AndroidRuntime(6052): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ListView$SavedState
05-09 14:04:55.019: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onRestoreInstanceState(AbsListView.java:1018)
05-09 14:04:55.019: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:6325)
05-09 14:04:55.019: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchThawSelfOnly(ViewGroup.java:1314)
05-09 14:04:55.019: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(AdapterView.java:767)
05-09 14:04:55.019: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:1301)
05-09 14:04:55.019: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:6304)
05-09 14:04:55.019: E/AndroidRuntime(6052):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.restoreViewState(Fragment.java:417)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this view is of a different type depending on orientation, saving state isn't necessary.  Disabling it via `setSaveEnabled` will remove this control from the `onSaveInstanceState`/`onRestoreInstanceState` events.

```
    list = (AbsListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setSaveEnabled(false);
```